# Integration of autocorrelation function when $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = 0$

Tags: integration, convolution, correlation

When $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = 0$ and $f(t)=0$ for $t\in \mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$, my conjecture is that
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} R_{ff}(\tau)\,d\tau = 0,
$$
where
$$
R_{ff}(\tau) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t+\tau) f(t)\,dt.
$$
How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(t) = 0$ for $t>1$ or $t<0$, it is enough to show
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-C}^C R_{ff}(\tau)\,d\tau,
\end{align*}
for some $C>1$.
By the integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
\def\bbR{{\mathbb{R}}}
\require{cancel}
 \int_{-C}^C R_{ff}(\tau)\,d\tau &= \cancelto{0}{\tau R_{ff}(\tau)\rvert_{-C}^C} - \int_{-C}^C \tau R'_{ff}(\tau)\,d\tau   \\
 &=- \int_{-C}^C \tau \int_{\bbR} f'(t+\tau) f(t)\,dt \,d\tau   \\
 &=- \int_{\bbR} \int_{-C}^C \tau  f'(t+\tau)\,d\tau  f(t)\,dt   \\
 &=- \int_{\bbR} \left( \cancelto{0}{\tau f(t+\tau) \rvert_{-C}^C} - \cancelto{0}{\int_{-C}^C f(t+\tau)\,d\tau} \right) f(t)\,dt  \\
 &=0.
\end{align*}